# uploading multiple files from client to server with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-io

uploading multiple files from client to server with asp.net

I have been looking at the asp.net upload control but that is for one file (unless someone knows a better way to do it).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

For what I want to do I don't even really need a browse. I know the files off of the client are at a certain location. Is it possible to create a collection of *HttpPostedFile*s and upload those?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx

I don't think it is possible but would be glad to be proven wrong. Is there a different asp.net method or control that will easily allow uploading multiple files from client to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few ideas to look over:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/UploadingMultipleFilesInASPDotNET203062009015325AM/UploadingMultipleFilesInASPDotNET2.aspx

http://aspalliance.com/1221_CodeSnip_Uploading_Multiple_Files_At_Once.all

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=68&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0):

The only multiple file upload component I know from the top of my head is the one Telerik provides:
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx

That's bundled in RadControls, which is a pretty nice kit to have, though it costs a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [**System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile(v=VS.80).aspx) and [**System.Net.WebClient.UploadFileAsync**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync(v=VS.80).aspx) methods.

If you use the **synchronous** method, you would upload **one file at a time** sequentially. If you opt for the **asynchronous** method instead, you could fire off **multiple uploads at once**.

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer Purifying the stuff  with HTML & JavaScript on the Client Side and on the Server Side Using Generic Handler if you are a JavaScript Developer it will be more easier and customizable in your hand and maybe you invent your way of uploading the files

i will tell you about my way of doing this technically

(1st) of course you need to make the upload process without posting the page back and forth to the server so in this case the main item here is an HTML Item which will help us uploading files without posting the whole page which is `IFRAME`.

(2nd) for most of us in the very beginning we knew the `FORM` tag is responsible of posting the data from client to server but we didn't know that if we had a INPUT FILE in our FORM we can't post its files to the server without adding a specific attribute in the form tag which is `enctype= multipart/form-data`

(3rd) there is many techniques invented to make the multiple upload the first one is by adding a attribute to the `INPUT FILE` which is `multiple="multiple"` that will make the input file acts to hold a multiple files inside it but in this case it will be a one by one multiple upload when posting the files all together in 1 request to the server.

the other technique is creating in the run time an input file for each file we need to upload with that we can pass the input files control to a form related to each that form of course is inside an IFRAME related to it  with that we have a request to each uploading process

to whom ever need more details about that technique free to ask for more description